# Run compiled python script with arguments in C++ (Cython)

Tags: python, c++, cythonize

What I try to achieve is **compiling my Python script to lib/dll and invoke it with arguments**.

This is my **setup.py** file for the script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("nu3k2nu4k.py")
)
```

Used this command to produce compilation outputs:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

following files produced:

```
nu3k2nu4k.c
nu3k2nu4k.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
nu3k2nu4k.pyx
```

and a subdirectory named build which contains:

```
nu3k2nu4k.cp36-win_amd64.exp
nu3k2nu4k.cp36-win_amd64.lib
nu3k2nu4k.obj
```

**How can I invoke the compiled script from c++ code with arguments?**

I used Cython for the task but that's not mandatory, boost or others could be used as well (I'm doing this to make the source code not accessible).

Edit:

Using the documentation provided by Mykola Shchetinin I have managed to generate an API header file for my script. I basically added a cdef api keyword to my main function. While this does help me export the method name to c++ I still need a way to pass around some arguments to my script. Since I pass string arguments I was hoping for a similar way like using PyRun to set argv and parse the arguments from the script (since I would like to avoid conversion of strings from c to python encoding if possible) Is there any easy way to pass those string arguments?

EDIT 2:

I got it working! following the sample provided by Mykola and directly compiling the c file output instead of using the .lib I got it working.

Comment: It is actually in the docs: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c

Comment: From the documentation it seems like I need to add a cdef api keyword to my main function in order to produce the header file needed. 
I'll give it a shot...

Comment: I managed to create an API header file for my script.
Is there any way to set the the arguments like in PyRun?
declaring the arguments as c types seems like a one ugly way for dealing with conversions from c strings to python and I would like to avoid that if possible...

Comment: I suggest you updating your question with what you achieved to make it easier to answer for other users. I have just pointed out what I have found in the docs...

Comment: Sure, just edited my question with my progress. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to do that by myself. So I convert `char *` to `bytes` in cython. (according to [docs](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html#accepting-strings-from-python-code))

That is what I came up with. I have the following setup (gcc and centos7.2):

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("func.pyx")
    )
```

**main.c**

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "func.h"

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    initfunc();
    func("0123hello jorghy!!");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**func.pyx**

```
cdef public func(char * arg):
    cdef bytes py_bytes = arg
    print(str(py_bytes));
```

I build all this stuff with the following commands:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace

gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 -Wall -Wextra -O2 -g -o test main.c func.c
```

Then when running the executable file **test** I get the following results:

```
0123hello jorghy!!
```

---

## UPDATE

There is another way to approach this problem:

I have created a cython file **test.pyx**:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hei")
    print(sys.argv)
```

And compiled as an executable it using commands:

```
cython test.pyx --embed
gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 -Wall -Wextra -O2 -g -o test test.c
```

Then you can call this code as an executable file:

```
$ ./test 1 2 3
hei
['./test', '1', '2', '3']
```

Then you can call it from C++ using [std::system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) or other (better) methods.

Comment: The behaviour is the same when I do not use `str()` call inside `print()`

Comment: I have tried to follow this example and did the same for me.
I have created same setup.py and func.pyx and compiled it the same for the first method.
I used this code to invoke the function:

    Py_Initialize();
    PyInit_func();

    func("0123hello jorghy!!");

    Py_Finalize();

I linked visual studio with the libary file produced from Cython and there was a linkage compilation error. the method signature was not exported to the lib file. When I tried to do similar method with api keyword instead of public it did compile but I got an exception. Thanks for the help with this.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the exception/ compilation error in visual studio.
I'll update what I got soon.

Comment: Probably something regarding Python.h, python2.7 libraries. I had to add `-I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7` arguments to my `gcc` compiler to avoid linkage errors (I use centos7.2). There should be something similar for visual studio C++ compiler on stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok! so I got it working when instead of using the lib file produced by Cython I did the same as you and directly compiled the .c file output. 
I got it working for a small sample project so I'll implement it in my project as well in no time. I have marked your answer as accepted, thanks for all the help.